# How do I change the Zebra ZP 450 left position with OS X?

Tags: osx-mavericks, zebra-printers, zpl

Please Help! I'm trying to print to a 1.5"x1.0" label on a Zebra ZP 450. The printer is connect to a Mac. When I print the label the printout is way over to the left. Only as small part of the bar code print out on the left side of the label. I'm guessing this is cause by the 'left position' in the printer settings. I tried calibrate (two flash and four flash) with no luck. I tried using zebrasetuputil app also with no luck (don't may not know enough of the programming to write it correctly).

Is there a terminal command I could use to change the default left position setting within the printer?

Sorry I'm new to all of this. Any help would be great!

OSX 10.11.1
Zebra ZP 450
Label Size: 1.5"x1.0"

Comment: How is this a programming question? You're probably looking for [apple.se] or [su] instead. This site is for programming (code) and programmer's tools related questions.

Comment: Hi ken, thanks for the message. My request does relate to programming code in OS X terminal.

Comment: I still don't see any indication of programming. If you're asking about a terminal command (from the command line), that's an OS use question and not a programming question. If your question is about **programming**, please [edit] and include information about what you've attempted to do in code to accomplish this task. If you can't do so, it's not a programming question and therefore it belongs on [apple.se] or [su].

Answer (score 1):

Send this command to the printer:

`^XA^LS0^XZ`

`^XA` Starts the format (always required)

`^LSa` sets the offset where `a = offset`

`^XZ` End format  (always required)

[See the ZPL Programming Guide](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/en-us/software/zplii-pm-vol1.pdf)

Additionally, there is a command you can set to prevent other labels from setting these offsets. (Sorry, don't know off the top of my head) It's a very good idea because ideally these offset should only be used for printers that are exhibiting wear, and need an offset to account for physical differences.

Using it for label formats will cause all sorts of problems with label formats that don't set it, because the labels that do set it will cause the ones that don't to be offset.